# Pre Installed OpenVAS , light way Linux

Tags: linux, vulnerability-scanners

Is there any Pre installed light way OpenVAS Linux distributions Or any light way Linux witch Openvas Tested on it and work properly on that Linux distribution ?

- I have used Back Track (UBUNTU Version) , it is not light way Linux with all that services and software and 4 Gig size.
- I seen [Openvas VM](http://www.openvas.org/vm.html) , it is about 4 Gig and i do not want to use this amount of hard disk space .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Kali Linux](http://www.kali.org/), the succesor to Backtrack offers a mini version of the distribution that is only 400MB. Alternatively, just build the package on any lightweight linux distributions like [Arch Linux](https://www.archlinux.org/).

Do note that I have encountered many issues with configuring OpenVAS in the past, to the points where I simply gave up. I recommend Nessus or Nexpose instead if being closed source isn't an issue for you. Both products offer a "free" edition that might be suitable for you.